Failures of greedy graph coloring
I'm working on an algorithm that, in a certain stage, requires solving a variation of the graph coloring problem. (The vertices are line segments in a plane, and two vertices are connected iff the line segments intersect. I also know there will never be a clique with more than five elements in the graph.) For now I'm using a standard greedy algorithm. But I'm curious how badly this algorithm can fail.
Specifically, I know the minimum number of colors used by a greedy algorithm is the chromatic number $\chi(G)$, and the maximum number used is the Grundy number. I'm curious about the difference between these. Is there a known upper bound on this difference?

The difference is $n-2$ in a crown graph with $2n$ vertices, so it can grow arbitrarily large.
